# Return the remaining string in c without using strtok

Tags: c

I would like to print the remaining string by a deliminator.

The expected output should be:

**String**

**in**

**C**

```
int main()
{
    /* loop over a string using subscript*/
    char *s = "String in C";
    char* ps;
    ps = s;
    while(*ps != ' ')
    {
        printf("%c",*ps);
        ps++;
    }
}
```

I can get the first **String**.

How can I get the rest of it?

Comment: Add an additional loop? (or use a state machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the best solution but it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *s = "String in C";
    char *ps;
    ps = s;
    while (*ps != '\0')
    {
        if (*ps == ' ')
        {
            printf("\n");
            *ps++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", *ps);
            ps++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh. It works. But if I return the value instead of using printf, how do I increment ps?

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't get "return the value"

Comment: I mean instead of using printf, I would like to use return. In that case, how can I increment?

Comment: `return` would cause the program to exit in this case you will get `String` then the program will find the `' '`will go into the conditions anl exits since it encountered a `return`

Answer (score 2):

You need to examine the logic of your program.

What you are doing right now is you stop iterating right after the first word, when the first space is encountered; that is what `while(*ps != ' ')` does.

Instead, you can iterate through the whole string, taking advantage of the fact that a string in C ends with a `\0`, i.e. `while (*ps != '\0')`.

Inside the `while` you can first test if the character is a blank, and if it is you can advance the pointer and skip to the next character using `continue`:

```
    if (*ps == ' ') {
        printf("\n");
        ps++;
        continue;
    }
```

Note that the code also prints a newline for readability. This `if` should also be first thing in the loop and this way it will also skip trailing blanks.

The rest of the code is what you have now, though you may want to add another newline printf after the `while` loop.